# How to change menu title color on mouse over (in java Swing)?

Tags: java, swing, menu, mouseover

i want the menu on the menu bar to change its background color on mouse over .. like in most applications.
i want this effect -> [Sample Picture](http://4.1m.yt/nNyf_lbxp.png)
what i tried so far ...

```
public class Menu extends JMenuBar implements ActionListener {

private JMenuItem fileItem_close;
private final MouseListener mouseAction = new MouseAdapter() { //i use this to apply the mouse event
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        JMenu item = (JMenu)e.getSource(); //is this implementation correct ?
        item.setOpaque(true);
    };

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        JMenu item = (JMenu)e.getSource(); 
        item.setOpaque(false);
    };
};


public Menu() {
    initFileMenu();
}

private void initFileMenu() {
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    fileMenu.setMnemonic('F');
    fileMenu.setRolloverEnabled(true);

    fileItem_close = new JMenuItem("Close");
    fileItem_close.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F4, KeyEvent.ALT_MASK)); //exit on pressing (Alt+F4)
    fileItem_close.addActionListener(this);

    fileMenu.add(fileItem_close);
    fileMenu.setRolloverEnabled(true);
    fileMenu.addMouseListener(mouseAction);
    fileMenu.setBackground(new Color(0x0066FF)); //The background is not visible as JMenu is not opaque by default.
    add(fileMenu);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JMenuItem source = (JMenuItem)e.getSource();
    if(source == fileItem_close)
        System.exit(0);     
}
}
```

The code above is not working, whenever i hover over that menu title nothing happen.
P.S: i'm not a GUI expert.
**EDIT :** *i'm using Nimbus LaF*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `setSelected()` for a hover effect. And yes, your implementation of `e.getSource()` was correct. So change it to these lines:

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    JMenu item = (JMenu) e.getSource(); // is this implementation
                                        // correct ?
    item.setSelected(true);
};

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    JMenu item = (JMenu) e.getSource();
    item.setSelected(false);
};
```

If you also want the menuitems to pop up on `mouseEntered()`, call `item.doClick()` in your `mouseEntered` method instead of setting it selected.

**Edit:**

For customization:

```
UIManager.put("Menu.selectionBackground", Color.BLUE);
UIManager.put("Menu.selectionForeground", Color.WHITE);
UIManager.put("Menu.background", Color.WHITE);
UIManager.put("Menu.foreground", Color.BLACK);
UIManager.put("Menu.opaque", false);
```

You can change these settings to any color you want, and it's more comfortable than creating an own class that extends `JMenu`.

If you also want to do this with other components (`JMenuItems`, for example), have a look at [this](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-uimanager-color-keys-list). You can find all `UIManager` color key values there.

**Edit 2:**

For Nimbus LAF, create a new class:

```
class FillPainter implements Painter<JComponent> {

    private final Color color;

    FillPainter(Color c) {
        color = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics2D g, JComponent object, int width, int height) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}
```

The above is required for the painting of the background. Now, do this:

```
for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("MenuBar:Menu[Selected].backgroundPainter",
                    new FillPainter(Color.BLUE));
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("MenuBar:Menu[Selected].textForeground", Color.WHITE);
            break;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

**For all other Nimbus LAF color key values, check [this](http://www.duncanjauncey.com/java/ui/uimanager/UIDefaults_Java1.6.0_11_Windows_2000_5.0_Nimbus.html)**

Comment: this worked well, but didn't give the background color i want .. it only display the default selection color.

Comment: that does it, but how to make it work with different LaFs ? (i.e. Nimbus)

Comment: @DaftPunk That I don't know right now, sorry. But I'll let you know if I find it out (maybe someone else knows it better)

Comment: OK thanks for the effort, i'll try to look this up :-) i'd vote up if i could

Comment: Thanks for attention. this worked! i was trying some keys for Nimbus but never noticed `"MenuBar:Menu[Selected].textForeground"`